# Problem with É; À; È with charter font

Tags: fonts, accents, overleaf

I'm using *charter* as my font for my thesis.

I just found out that the É, À and È have problem with their accents. The accents are too low and superpose the letter itself. I think it is due to the documentClass i'm using. Here is an exemple:

```
\documentclass{ULrapport}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{charter}

\title{Tests Latex}
\author{Marc-André Vigneault}
\date{April 2019}

\begin{document}

\section{Électronique}

\end{document}
```

This gives this output:

[image]

Here's the class

```
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------- identification -----------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{ULrapport}%
              [2011/01/14 v1.1h Classe de rapport technique - Universite Laval]

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%------------------------------------ initial code ------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Flags logiques permettant l'insertion des listes des figures et des tableaux
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{InsererListeDesFigures}
\newboolean{InsererListeDesTableaux}


%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%------------------------------- declaration of options -------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DeclareOption{ULlof}{\setboolean{InsererListeDesFigures}{true}}
\DeclareOption{ULlot}{\setboolean{InsererListeDesTableaux}{true}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%-------------------------------- execution of options --------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\ProcessOptions \relax

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------- package loading ----------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\LoadClass{report}

\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[USenglish,french]{babel}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}        % pour \textcelsius, \textmu, \textohm
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{amstext}         % pour \text
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{colortbl}
\RequirePackage{longtable}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{rotating}
% \RequirePackage{mathabx}         % pour \second (peut etre remplace par "\prime\prime")
% \RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%-------------------------------------- main code -------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Definitions des parametres du package hyperref
\hypersetup{plainpages=false,%
            breaklinks=false,%
            colorlinks=true}

% Definitions des dimensions de la page (package geometry)
\geometry{letterpaper,%
          centering,%
          hmargin={2.5cm,2.5cm},%
          vmargin={2.5cm,2.5cm},%
          heightrounded,%
          includehead}

% Utilisation du package "caption" pour
%    - redefinit le caractere de separation dans les legendes comme "babel" le definit,
%      car "caption" (ou "float", le cas echeant) le redefinit comme ":"
%    - uniformise les legendes entre table, longtable et supertabular
%    - specifie que la legende des tableaux sera placee en haut,
%      donc intervertit les dimensions d'espacements (avant et apres la legende)
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{as-Babel-french}{\space\textendash\space}
\captionsetup{margin=0.1\textwidth,labelsep=as-Babel-french}
\captionsetup[table]{position=top}


% Redefinition de l'environnement "thebibliography" afin que son existence soit
% mentionnee a la table des matieres
\newenvironment{thebibliographyUL}[1]%
               {\clearpage%
                \begin{thebibliography}{#1}%
                \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}%
                \raggedright%
               }%
               {\end{thebibliography}}


% En-tete et bas de page par defaut
\pagestyle{headings}


% Definitions pour l'inclusion de graphiques
%    - des repertoires par defaut
%    - des extensions supportees
\graphicspath{{./fig/}}

% Definitions de la page titre
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
   \thispagestyle{empty}%
   \pagenumbering{roman}%
   \begin{titlepage}%
      \setcounter{page}{999}%                      % associe le numero "0" a la page titre
      \begin{flushleft}
         \includegraphics[width=12em]{ul_logo}
      \end{flushleft}\par
      \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
      \begin{center}
         \parbox{\textwidth}{\centering\Large\bfseries \theTitreProjet}         \\[5ex]
         \parbox{\textwidth}{\centering\large\bfseries \theTitreRapport}        \\
         \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
         pr\'{e}sent\'{e} \`{a}                    \\[1ex]
         \textbf{\theDestinataire}                 \\
         \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
         par                                       \\[1ex]
         {\large \'{E}quipe \theNumeroEquipe\
                 --- \theNomEquipe}                \\[1ex]
      \end{center}
      \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}            % plus d'espace pour les signatures
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}%
         {|l|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}
         \hline
         \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\emph{matricule}}
         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\emph{nom}}
         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\emph{signature}}
         \\\hline
         \theTableauMembres
      \end{tabularx}\par
      \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
      \begin{center}
         {\large Universit\'{e} Laval}             \\
         \theDateRemise
      \end{center}
   \end{titlepage}%
   \clearpage%
   \let\maketitle\relax%
}


% Definitions des fonctions permettant de definir les parametres de la page titre
%
%\newcommand{\theTitreProjet}{\foreignlanguage{french}{Titre du projet}}                  % Titre du projet
%\newcommand{\TitreProjet}[1]{\renewcommand{\theTitreProjet}{\foreignlanguage{french}{#1}}}           % Titre du projet
\def\TitreProjet#1{\def\theTitreProjet{#1}}           % Titre du projet
\def\TitreRapport#1{\def\theTitreRapport{#1}}         % Titre du rapport
\def\Destinataire#1{\def\theDestinataire{#1}}         % Nom(s) du destinataire
\def\NumeroEquipe#1{\def\theNumeroEquipe{#1}}         % Numero de l'equipe
\def\NomEquipe#1{\def\theNomEquipe{#1}}               % Nom de l'equipe
\def\TableauMembres#1{\def\theTableauMembres{#1}}     % Tableau des membres de l'equipe
\def\DateRemise#1{\def\theDateRemise{#1}}             % Date de remise
\def\HistoriqueVersions#1%
   {\def\theHistoriqueVersions{#1}}                   % Historique des versions


% Definitions des parametres par defaut de la page titre
\def\theTitreProjet{Titre du projet}                  % Titre du projet
\def\theTitreRapport{Titre du rapport}                % Titre du rapport
\def\theDestinataire{Destinataire}                    % Nom(s) du destinataire
\def\theNumeroEquipe{XX}                              % Numero de l'equipe
\def\theNomEquipe{Nom de l'\'{e}quipe}                % Nom de l'equipe
\def\theTableauMembres{matricule & nom & \\\hline}    % Tableau des membres de l'equipe
\def\theDateRemise{Date de remise}                    % Date de remise
\def\theHistoriqueVersions%
   {version & date & description \\\hline}            % Historique des versions


% Definition du niveau hierarchique maximum couvert par la table des matieres
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}            % default = 2

% Definition du niveau hierarchique maximum ayant une numerotation
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}         % default = 2

% Definitions des parametres du package hyperref - details propres au rapport
\AtBeginDocument{%
   \hypersetup{pdftitle={\theTitreProjet},%
               pdfsubject={\theTitreRapport},%
               pdfauthor={\'{E}quipe \theNumeroEquipe\ - \theNomEquipe}}%
}

% Selection de la langue "babel" par defaut
\AtBeginDocument{%
   \selectlanguage{french}%
}

% Changement des mots utilises par "babel" par defaut (figure et table)
\AtBeginDocument{%
   \renewcommand{\figurename}{\textsc{Figure}}%
   \renewcommand{\tablename}{\textsc{Tableau}}%
}

% Generation de la page titre
\AtBeginDocument{%
   \maketitle
}

% Generation de la page d'historique des versions ("Document Change Record")
\AtBeginDocument{%
   \thispagestyle{empty}%
   \setcounter{page}{0}%
   \noindent%
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}%
      {|c|l|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}
      \hline\hline
      \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\large\rule[-2.25ex]{0ex}{6ex}%
                           \textsf{Historique des versions}}
      \\\hline
      \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\emph{version}}
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\emph{date}}
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\emph{description}}
      \\\hline
      \theHistoriqueVersions\hline
   \end{tabularx}\par
   \clearpage
}

% Generation de la table des matieres, de la liste des figures, de la liste des tableaux
\AtBeginDocument{%
   \tableofcontents
   %\ifthenelse{\boolean{InsererListeDesFigures}}%
    %          {\clearpage%
    %           \listoffigures
    %           \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}}{}
   %\ifthenelse{\boolean{InsererListeDesTableaux}}%
     %         {\clearpage%
     %          \listoftables
     %          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}}{}
}

% Reinitialisation du compteur "page" (valeur et style)
\AtBeginDocument{%
   \cleardoublepage%
   \setcounter{page}{1}%
   \pagenumbering{arabic}%
}
```

Is there a way to fix this problem?
I really can't find out what is interfering with the charter package.

I have printed \listfiles  in the log file. Here is the log \listfiles:

```
    *File List*
ULrapport.cls    2011/01/14 v1.1h Classe de rapport technique - Universite Lava
l
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  report.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
   babel.sty    2017/06/29 3.12 The Babel package
USenglish.ldf    2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
 frenchb.ldf    2017/04/30 v3.3a French support from the babel system
scalefnt.sty    
 caption.sty    2016/02/21 v3.3-144 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2016/05/22 v1.7-166 caption3 kernel (AR)
textcomp.sty    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
   array.sty    2016/10/06 v2.4d Tabular extension package (FMi)
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
tabularx.sty    2016/02/03 v2.11 `tabularx' package (DPC)
colortbl.sty    2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)
   color.sty    2016/07/10 v1.1e Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2017/06/24 v1.0g Graphics/color driver for pdftex
longtable.sty    2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
rotating.sty    2016/08/11 v2.16d rotated objects in LaTeX
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
hyperref.sty    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
 hpdftex.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ts1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
 charter.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (P.Dyballa) 
  ts1cmr.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
   t1bch.fd    2004/10/18 font definitions for T1/bch.
ltcaption.sty    2013/06/09 v1.4-94 longtable captions (AR)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
  output.out
  output.out
ul_logo-eps-converted-to.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
  ot1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  omllmm.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omslmsy.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omxlmex.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  t1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 ***********
```

Comment: Are you using the Type1 Charter in TeX Live? The OpenType XCharter? How are you entering the accented letters in your source?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You won't have this problem with `xcharter`.

Comment: I can't reproduce, [click here for a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqiJI.png)

Comment: Nor if you download the OTF version of Bitstream Charter (or its derivative, Charis SIL) and load it with `fontspec` and `\setmainfont{Bitstream Charter}[Scale=1.0]`.

Comment: I tried each and every suggestion, but I still have the same problem. I'll add a list of the packages I use. Maybe you'll notice something that isn't compatible...

Comment: With the long list of packages I only get an error when loading `subcaption` after `subfig` (which is a wrong thing to do and the error message is self-explanatory). But I get all the accents right exactly as in the picture I showed yesterday.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it should have been commented... That's really weird... Do you think that the documentClass can have an impact on the fonts? I use a personnal class that is given by my university.

Comment: Everything regular on my system also with the ULrapport class.

Comment: @PyThagoras With your documentclass everything works fine. Are all your packages up-to-date? Can you place `\listfiles` in the preamble and show us the list of packages this prints into the log file?

Comment: I have verified again, for me it is definitely the reason of this problem. If I use article class instead, I do not have the problem. I'll add what you ask in the preamble.

Comment: Some packages are really outdates, for example report.cls is currently `2018/09/03 v1.4i` Update your tex distribution

Comment: I am using Overleaf. So I guess it is their distribution that is outdated?

Comment: @PyThagoras Definitely, they have a long outdated texlive version. They said they will update to the now already old one from last year in a couple of months, so they will probably be never up-to-date

Comment: I better find an alternative font then :'( Thank you all for your replies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is the result of an outdated distribution at Overleaf.

Comment: It is worth noting that Overleaf updated their system in September 2019 to TeX live 2018 (https://www.overleaf.com/blog/tex-live-upgrade-september-2019). Maybe that is already new enough so that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overleaf unfortunately uses a long outdated texlive version. In particular the packages related to the fontencoding seems too old. The following MWE reproduces the problem on overleaf

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{charter}

\begin{document}

\section{Électronique}

\end{document}
```

Until overleaf will finally update their texlive version, maybe another encoding could work around the problem:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{charter}

\begin{document}

\section{Électronique}

\end{document}
```

Test document on overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/mgpmnnqkqwdq

[image]